# Last select option not highlighted on mouse hover in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My HTML:

```
<select id="start_time">
    <option value="00:00">0:00</option>
    <option value="00:30">0:30</option>
    <option value="01:00">1:00</option>
    <option value="01:30">1:30</option>
    <option value="02:00">2:00</option>
    <option value="02:30">2:30</option>
    <option value="03:00">3:00</option>
    <option value="03:30">3:30</option>
    <option value="04:00">4:00</option>
    <option value="04:30">4:30</option>
    <option value="05:00">5:00</option>
    <option value="05:30">5:30</option>
    <option value="06:00">6:00</option>
    <option value="06:30">6:30</option>
    <option value="07:00">7:00</option>
    <option value="07:30">7:30</option>
    <option value="08:00">8:00</option>
    <option value="08:30">8:30</option>
    <option value="09:00">9:00</option>
    <option value="09:30">9:30</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
    <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
    <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
    <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
    <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
    <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
    <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
    <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
    <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
    <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
    <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
    <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
    <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
    <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
    <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
    <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
    <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
    <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
    <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
    <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
    <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
    <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPq2Z/).

When you run this, if the user opens the dropdown box the cursor doesn't turn blue in the last box.

Is this a Chrome bug? Or is there a change I needed to correct it?

Comment: Works fine here in Chrome 33 beta?

Comment: So it is not my fault :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a Chrome 32 bug. [The issue in Chromium bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334227).

Answer (score 0):

It's a chrome bug ;-), i was brainfarting about it too :p!